# Homebrew's formula-like object creation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop

I'd like to create an object in Ruby by extending a class (like in [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/binutils.rb)):

```
class Somepackage < Formula
    version "2.8"
    homepage "http://foo.bar.com/"
end
```

However, I'm a Ruby recruit and I can't find a way to define the `Formula` class that would fit my needs:

```
class Formula
    attr_reader :version, :homepage
    def self.version (version)
        @version = version
    end
end
```

This obviously doesn't work:

```
Somepackage.version #=> nil
```

(I need it to return `2.8`)

I know it must be a very simple thing to do, but I tried various combinations and just can't make it.

**Update**

Ok, so, thanks to Sergio's answer, the final version looks like this:

```
def property(*properties)
  properties.each do |prop|
    self.class_eval("def self.#{prop}(#{prop} = nil); @#{prop} = #{prop} if #{prop}; @#{prop}; end")
  end
end

class Formula
    property :version, :homepage
end

class Somepackage < Formula
   version "2.8"
   homepage "http://foo.bar.com/"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your `attr_reader` methods are on instance level. To call them you'd need to do this

```
Somepackage.new.version
```

which obviously was not your intent. You can promote them to class level like this:

```
class Formula
  class << self
    attr_reader :version, :homepage
  end

  def version(version)
    @version = version
  end
end
```

But here's a problem as well. Your second version of `version` overwrites `version` from `attr_reader`. As a result, you have a method which can set values, but not return. After some experiments, you'll end up with something like this:

```
class Formula
  def self.version(version = nil)
    if version
      @version = version
    end

    @version
  end
end

class Somepackage < Formula
  version "2.8"
end

Somepackage.version # => "2.8"
```

Make your own version for `homepage`. Or, better yet, write a method that generates these methods, so that you can just do

```
class Formula
  property :version, :homepage
end
```

Comment: Following your advice, I wrote the method-generator method and posted its source in my question update. Thank you! :)